# Getting help text instead of running script with Windows ftp

Tags: ftp

I'm on windows 8.1 and using ftp from the cmd console (run as administrator).

If I enter:

```
ftp -v -i -A thispc
```

**Note:** "thispc" is mapped in the hosts file to my local ip address

If I then enter:

```
mput *.*
```

all the files in my current folder get pushed to my ftp server.

However, if I try to do this from a .bat file, it does not work.

The .bat file:

```
@echo off
ftp -v -i -A thispc -s:send_file.txt
```

The contents of send_file.txt:

```
mput *.*
quit
```

I get the ftp help text instead when I run it via this .bat file with the following note:

```
mget and mput commands take y/n/q for yes/no/quit
```

The `-i` in the ftp call is supposed to disable that.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work.

Comment: You need turn prompt off to use mput in bat

Comment: The note is part of the help text. It's not a note specific to your script. It's actually irrelevant to your script, as with your incorrect syntax, the `ftp` does not even try to load the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - figured it out.

Quite simply:

```
ftp -v -i -A -s:send_file.bat thispc
```

instead of:

```
ftp -v -i -A thispc -s:send_file.txt
```

The error messages from ftp are not very useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
prompt
mput *.*
quit
```

In you input file.

Comment: This makes no difference when run from the .bat file.  Whether I include `-i` or not